# How to use richedit control _RICHEDIT_VER over 2.1 in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, version, richedit, cricheditctrl

I'd like to use Rich edit control's underline color in MFC

but, in afxwin.h, _RICHEDIT_VER define 0x210. 
like this,

```
#define _RICHEDIT_VER 0x0210
```

I'm loading 'msftedit.dll'(8.1 Version) and Windows10 SDK (10.0.16299.0)
but, bUnderlineColor is coded in Richedit.h

```
#if (_RICHEDIT_VER >= 0x0800)
    BYTE        bUnderlineColor;    // Underline color
#endif
```

If I don't use wrapping class(CRichEditCtrl), Can I use this in MFC project.
and How?

Comment: Is this solution suitable for you ? https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/richedit/editorsandediting/how-to-use-richeditcontrol-41-in-cricheditview.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare your own structure and add `bUnderlineColor`. Use this in `CRichEdit::SendMessage(EM_SETCHARFORMAT...)`

This method is hack though. Maybe there is a better way to convince MFC to cooperate.

```
#ifdef UNICODE
struct MY_CHARFORMAT8 : _charformatw //<--- edited
#else
struct MY_CHARFORMAT8 : _charformat
#endif
{
    WORD        wWeight;            // Font weight (LOGFONT value)
    SHORT       sSpacing;           // Amount to space between letters
    COLORREF    crBackColor;        // Background color
    LCID        lcid;               // Locale ID
    union
    {
        DWORD       dwReserved;     // Name up to 5.0
        DWORD       dwCookie;       // Client cookie opaque to RichEdit
    };
    SHORT       sStyle;             // Style handle
    WORD        wKerning;           // Twip size above which to kern char pair
    BYTE        bUnderlineType;     // Underline type
    BYTE        bAnimation;         // Animated text like marching ants
    BYTE        bRevAuthor;         // Revision author index
    BYTE        bUnderlineColor;    // Underline color
};

MY_CHARFORMAT8 format;
memset(&format, sizeof(format), 0);
format.cbSize = sizeof(format);
format.dwMask = CFM_UNDERLINETYPE | CFM_UNDERLINE;
format.dwEffects = CFE_UNDERLINE;
format.crBackColor = RGB(255,0,0);
format.bUnderlineType = CFU_UNDERLINEHAIRLINE;
format.bUnderlineColor = 0x06; //red underline color
m_richedit.SetSel(0, -1);
m_richedit.SendMessage(EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&format);
```

Requires initial call to `AfxInitRichEdit()`

Rich edit control has to be created manually with `Create` (not using `SubclassDlgItem` or `DDX_Control`), example:

```
m_richedit.Create(ES_MULTILINE | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, rc, this, id);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Edited: needs separate declaration for `UNICODE`

Comment: You are welcom @JaeHyeokKim, I had to make changes, see edit